# Exceptions. How do I fix that? First steps

Tags: java, exception

few weeks ago I have starded learning java. Im new and I make many mistakes. Today Im trying to learn about exceptions. I wrote a program which compute square of rectangle, but it doesnt works when i put in side "a" for example c letter. I would like if it shows to me string like "We have a problem ;)", but it throws error. Can you help me?

```
package Learning;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exceptions {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double a,b,wynik;
        Scanner odc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter side a: ");
            a = odc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter side b: ");
            b = odc.nextDouble();
            wynik=a*b;
            System.out.println("Field equals: "+wynik);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("We have a problem ;)");
        }
    }
}
```

When i put in side a, "c" letter i have something like that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at Learning.Exceptions.main(Exceptions.java:11)
```

I need to see: "We have a problem ;)"

Comment: You could try to extend your catch block by also catching java.util.InputMismatchException

Answer (score 2):

catch the `InputMismatchException`:

```
catch(NumberFormatException | InputMismatchException e){ ... }
```

`System.out.println("We have a problem ;)");` will be executed if either a  `NumberFormatException` or `InputMismatchException` arises.

if you want to output different result based on the exception type then create another `catch` block for `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: Thank You very much :) You soleved my problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Your code never throw any `NumberFormatException`.
The impossibility to convert the input to a `double` is already conveyed by `InputMismatchException`.

Note that `NumberFormatException` and `InputMismatchException` are unchecked exceptions (they derive from RuntimeException).
This kind of exception may be thrown even if these are not declared as thrown by any invoked methods.
So generally you may want to catch them  because you know that they may be thrown and you want to handle it. 
But you should be aware to catch only them when these may be effectively thrown as it makes code clearer.
Here it is not the case.

So in your case that is enough :

```
try {
    System.out.println("Enter side a: ");
    a = odc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter side b: ");
    b = odc.nextDouble();
    wynik=a*b;
    System.out.println("Field equals: "+wynik);
}
catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("We have a problem ;)");
}
```